# Entity Framework : specific setup for 2 classes and relation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class AdvertiserConcern
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required int ConcernId { get;set; }
    public required int AdvertiserId { get;set; }

    public Client? Concern { get; set; }
    public Client? Advertiser { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AdvertiserConcern>? AdvertiserConcernsAdvertisers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AdvertiserConcern>? AdvertiserConcernsConcerns { get; set; }
}
```

I am struggling with the relation from `Client` to `AdvertiserConcern`. I started with only `advertisers`, but was also not able to get it work. I was adding `[ForeignKey("AdvertiserId")]` on `Advertiser` navigation property on `AdvertiserConcern` and adding `[InverseProperty("Advertiser")]` on `Client.AdvertiserConcernsAdvertisers` , when creating the migration it acutally wants to add a column `ClientID` on `AdvertiserConcern`, which is already there with `AdvertiserId`.

I can probably achieve it with Fluent API, but rather have it clear on the models. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this a 1:n 1:1 or n:n relationship?

Comment: your title is a bit misleading.  You're attempting to build 2 entity models with 2 relations (relationships) between them without fluent api.  Putting aside the scope of this Q&A -- when I look at models here, I think what you're actually trying to achieve is [Inheritance - EFCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).  This comes down to using a Discriminator field for the Type.  where `AdvertiserConcern` inherits from `Concern` (a separate class and model).

Comment: i left other properties out of the entity for "clearity'. But we have many clients with a disciminator, i.e.; clientType. But for some of them there is a relation between them. Hence the AdvertiserConcern table. Just to connect 2 clients together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases,`EF` can recognize relationships based on convention, but when two or more foreign keys from one table exist in another table, you should explicitly configure the relationships in `OnModelCreating` method using the `FLUENT API` as follows :

```cs
  modelBuilder.Entity<AdvertiserConcern>(entity =>
  {
      entity.HasOne(s => s.Advertiser)
          .WithMany(d => d.AdvertiserConcernsAdvertisers)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.AdvertiserId);

      entity.HasOne(s => s.Concern)
          .WithMany(d => d.AdvertiserConcernsConcerns)
         .HasForeignKey(d => d.ConcernId); 
  });
```

Comment: yeah, that is how i solved it now. Was unable to get it working with data-annotations.